"Only active directory users can impersonate other active directory users" exception on procedure using WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
A similar question has been asked previously, but the OP answered it themself and the context here is different and so has not benefited my understand about how to best address the challenge.  I'm specifically looking for a solution based on minimal admin burden and security best practice please.
We're migrating a database from on-premise to SQL Azure Databases (not SQLMI).  We have about 600 stored procedures which are executed by a web application.  The web application uses a user account that has EXECUTE privileges on the procedures only and nothing else.
Five of these procedures need to disable then re-enabled a table trigger during execution, so historically we've used WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER to achieve this.  However, in SQL Azure these specific procedures throw an exception:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Only active directory users can impersonate other active directory users.'

Is my solution correct?
I read up on WITH EXECUTE AS and also ALTER AUTHORIZATION which led me to use the following solution, which did work but I'm not sure if there are other more suitable methods based on my use-case.
CREATE USER TriggerUser WITHOUT LOGIN; -- No requirement for this user account to be used outside this process
GO
GRANT ALTER ON [MyTable] TO [TriggerUser]; -- Allow suspension of trigger
GO

Then in each respective procedure:
CREATE OR ALTER PROC MyProc 
WITH EXECUTE AS USER = 'TriggerUser' AS ...

Further clarification required on the error
During my research I tried the following statements with results that surprised me:
EXEC sys.sp_stored_procedures @sp_name=N'MyProcedureThatAltersTheTrigger'

This shows the PROCEDURE_OWNER as dbo which I believe is the schema and not the user account.  I then found the following from another SO post to show schema owners:
SELECT db.name AS [DB User], s.name AS [Schema]
FROM sys.database_principals db
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.principal_id = db.principal_id

This shows that the dbo schema is owned by the dbo user.  I was therefore confused by this part of the error, "can impersonate other active directory users".  Why is SQL Azure opting to impersonate another active directory user when dbo isn't an AD user please?
Responses to comments
Running the following query...
SELECT
    db.name
   ,db.owner_sid AS DBOwnerName
   ,dp.name DbPrincipalName
   ,sp.name ServerPrincipalName
FROM
    master.sys.databases db
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON db.owner_sid = dp.sid
    LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals   sp ON db.owner_sid = sp.sid
;

...shows that the database's owner maps to the Azure Entra login (my personal login) used to create the SQL Server.  This differed from the other databases on the server which map to a SQL Server principal (and not related to an Entra principal).  I also remembered that SSMS locally was used to create this database using a DACPAC due to issues with speed reported in the Azure import database wizard.

Who owns the database? I'm not sure if this works in Azure, but try select suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases where name = 'yourDB'; If it's an AD account and the user executing the proc isn't, that's the disconnect.

'SUSER_SNAME' cannot be invoked with parameters in this version of SQL Server..  Is there a further query I can use to get the user from the sid without suser_sname?

I'd continue the search by looking in sys.server_principals, specifically in the sid column. But if that doesn't work, start doing some research - you know what you're looking for now (i.e. the database owner), now it's time to find out how to find it.

Question updated with more detail.  Perhaps this is the cause and ALTER AUTH ON DATABASE should be used to map back the same SQL login as the other database's...?  Opinions welcome!

I would change the database owner to match the others on the server. Which, if I'm reading correctly, is a SQL login. And going back to your issue, at that point your application login (whether AD or SQL) shouldn't have problems impersonating it because of the execute as clause.

That's fixed it, thank you.


dbo is the owner of the schema. But since dbo is a special account, the owner of the database, which is at top of the hierarchy, is the actual owner (often sa, in your case your Entra ID account).
It looks like this is one of probably many error messages that have not been properly adjusted for the use with Entra ID/Azure AD. Naturally this is confusing.
Most importantly: Yes, your solution is valid and pretty much locked down. Instead of running the whole proc under this elevated execution context, you could also run solely the respective command within the proc using EXECUTE AS under that account and then revert.

PS: compliments on the comprehensive, nicely-researched and well formatted description of your issue

Thanks @Andreas, I appreciate the follow up and clarity.  I also posted an alternative solution which worked better for me, but again I'm not sure how suitable this is for the wider context...?

Based on the specific context of this issue, which is because the database was created via SSMS as part of the Import BACPAC routine (and therefore my personal Azure AD account was set to the owner as part of the creation process, instead of the Azure SQL Server administrator user).
By running this command after database creation, ownership was reset to the Azure SQL Server administrator account.  This also served the benefit of not requiring the additional TriggerUser account:
-- Swap authorization from dbo back to Azure SQL Server admin
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON 
   DATABASE::MyDatabaseName
TO 
   MyAzureSqlServerAdminUsername; -- Account username specified when creating Azure SQL Server instance in Azure

From this point, the stored procedure executed okay.

Yes, this makes sense.
By changing the owner to an account that is not a real person, you are also in a safer spot altogether.
Best would be for Microsoft to come up with a special account type for such ownerships. But as long as we do not have that, the ServerAdmin is unfortunately the most practical solution

Amazing, thanks Andreas
